# Gdx.input.justTouched() is not working on all devices

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a game in LibGdx for android device. I could see a strange issue in using Gdx.input.justTouched(). It is working in some device and not in some device. Could you please help me if my code needs any correction?

```
@Override
public void create() { 
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);  
}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        System.out.println("inside : "  );
        dragNew = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
        dragOld = dragNew; 
    }
}
```

Comment: On what devices does it (not) work?  What exactly does "not working" mean -- i.e. what specifically do you expect and what specifically happens instead?

Comment: The control is not going inside the if clause " if (Gdx.input.justTouched())" hence my Vector2 objects are not getting initialized.  Device Xiomi - OK, Micromax - Not OK

Comment: I recommend not to use justTouched. Overwrite the  touchUp() and touchDown() methods of your InputProcessor

Comment: yes i did that, it was fine. Thanks !

Comment: Really? Do I have to change my code? How many devices are we talking about and is this confirmed?

Comment: @MennoGouw I used justTouched in a couple of apps with a few hundred thousand users with no complaints. I think the OP must have left out some details.

Comment: I checked micromax device, has good market in India. Devices are TAB - "Funbook P300" and Phone "A47" both are failing. Good with Xiaomi

Comment: With just two devices failing i should be ok. Thanks.

Comment: I tried in these 2 . who knows about the other devices :)